# Create infinite sessions in codeigniter php framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I am trying to create a session last forever in php, with codeignter framework.

My session settings at config.php are :

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'org_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'org_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Eventhough the expiration is zero, still session expires after browser closes. Any idea how to make this work? I am use mysql database to store session data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)

The value 0 means "until the browser is closed." Defaults to 0.

Comment: Oops! Thanks.

Any idea how to persist it even after browser is closed?

Answer (score 0):

I think using conditions, if the ip adress an the cookies params have especific info then redirect index page, and not to login page

```
if($ipaddress == 'foo' && $cookie['infinity'] == 'true'){
  $info= $model->getuser($ipaddress);
  if($info){
    redirect('index.php');
  }else{
    redirect('login.php);
  }
}
```